# Concatenating certain parts of a list. Removing spaces.

Tags: python, list, concatenation, list-comprehension, spaces

I have a list of names split up letter by letter, I would like to concatenate the individual names together. 
This is what I currently have:

`['S', 't', 'u', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'S', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'A', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'w', ' ', 'L', 'u', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'e', 'y', ' ', 'L', 'u', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'l', 'e', 'y', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'l', 'e',  'y', ' ', 'R', 'o', 'b', ' ']`

I would like to turn it into this:

```
['Stuart', 'Steve', 'Andrew', 'Luke', 'Shaney', 'Luke', 'Moley', 'Moley', 'Rob']
```

Comment: `''.join(your_list).split()`

Comment: This is possible but how did you get the first list? You should put the data in a better format in the first place instead of getting it into this messed up one and trying to fix it.

Comment: @vaultah That will result in a string, not a list.

Comment: @vaultah I appreciate the feedback but that's not what I'm aiming for unfortunately.

Comment: @Shaney96 that does precisely what you claim you want...

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I am reading from a text file. I broke up the text and placed it into a list, I'm now wondering how to get it so it recognizes when a space is present and it concatenates the data accordingly. I'm not sure how though

Comment: @jonrsharpe the comment was edited and originally said only `''.join(your_list)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe It doesn't, what ''.join() does is turns it into a string, I want it in a list, as I stated in my original question.

Comment: @Shaney96 `''.join(your_list).split()` does the trick

Comment: @Shaney96 I highly recommend asking a new question with your original text file and the code you are using to parse it. The correct solution is not to get into this situation in the first place, as I said.

Comment: Ahh it's been edited, thanks @vaultah, that works and is exactly what I am looking for! Cheers man

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The question I asked was fine, it was straightforward and the first (now edited) response was the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `info` be your list.

```
concat = "".join(info)
names = concat.split()
print names
```

But see the comment of Two-Bit Alchemist.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and group using [`str.isspace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = ['S', 't', 'u', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'S', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'A', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'w', ' ', 'L', 'u', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'e', 'y', ' ', 'L', 'u', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'l', 'e', 'y', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'l', 'e',  'y', ' ', 'R', 'o', 'b', ' ']
>>> [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=str.isspace) if not k]
['Stuart', 'Steve', 'Andrew', 'Luke', 'Shaney', 'Luke', 'Moley', 'Moley', 'Rob']
```

> I am reading from a text file. I broke up the text and placed it into
>   a list, I'm now wondering how to get it so it recognizes when a space
>   is present and it concatenates the data accordingly. I'm not sure how
>   though

I am not sure how you read this text, but you're processing it incorrectly. Don't call `list()` on the line or the whole text you've read from the file:

```
>>> s = 'Stuart Steve Andrew Luke Shaney Luke Moley Moley Rob'
>>> list(s)
['S', 't', 'u', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'S', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'A', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'w', ' ', 'L', 'u', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'e', 'y', ' ', 'L', 'u', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'l', 'e', 'y', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'l', 'e', 'y', ' ', 'R', 'o', 'b']
```

If you want a list of words simply use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the text you've read:

```
>>> s.split()
['Stuart', 'Steve', 'Andrew', 'Luke', 'Shaney', 'Luke', 'Moley', 'Moley', 'Rob']
```

Comment: Cheers for linking your response to the context, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the chars in the list, here is a little example:

```
# chars being your list
names = []

current_name = ""
for current_char in chars:
     if current_char == ' ':
         names.append(current_name)
         current_name = ""
     else:
          current_name += current_char

 return names
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering `li` to be the input list -

```
>>> [i for i in "".join(li).split(" ") if i.strip() != ""]
['Stuart', 'Steve', 'Andrew', 'Luke', 'Shaney', 'Luke', 'Moley', 'Moley', 'Rob']
```

The list comprehension is to just exclude empty strings.